# Delete a graph of objects efficiently

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a web application, and it uses **JPA, Hibernate, and MS SQL Server 2014** Enterprise. I have an account object, which owns other objects, which owns other objects, .... When I delete an account object owninga few objects, the delete does not show any probem. However, when an account has a large number of objects at different levels (3 to 4 levels in depth), the delete operation seems never ending.

What is the common strategy in deleting a large graph of objects in JPA?

**Update**

The account object is deleted through Spring Data such as the following in a service object (middle-layer):

```
accountRepository.delete(account);
```

Yes, the cascading delete is working. I am able to delete an account object with just a few records in each level. But the delete operation seems never ending when the second level has 16,000 objects and this level owns many other objects.

Comment: At least you need to show us how you do the delete now, before we can give comment why it is slow

Comment: Also tell us which DB you use

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server.

Comment: Is your DB configured to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` or is the job done by the Hibernate itself? @Adrian is right, you need also show us how you do the deletion.